# Правильно ли раставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В качестве логического шага, после многих лет поступательного позитивного развития, в декабре 2014 года в Санкт-Петербурге была основана российская дочерняя компания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Авторское обособление: связано с распространенностью обстоятельства, также определяет его пояснительный характер.

Comment: Соглашусь с тем, что здесь авторская пунктуация и мне кажется, что без запятых такое предложение действительно выглядит не очень.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, здесь ни одной запятой не нужно: идут различные члены предложения, нет ни обособления, ни перечисления, ни уточнения...

Answer (score 0):

*Смотря на эту работу, я не чувствую плохого настроения.*